# How to work with phylogenetic trees?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, trees

A phylogenetic tree can be represented as a comma-bracket string by the [Newick format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format) (see the [Newick Standard](http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/newicktree.html), or [this site](http://marvin.cs.uidaho.edu/Teaching/CS515/newickFormat.html) for syntax details; here is an [online tree visualizer](http://etetoolkit.org/treeview/)). A simple Newick string example is resolved as follows:

```
"(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F;"
```

[image]

Note, that a `(b1, b2, ...)node` represents a tree rooted at `node`, with branches in the parenthesis; any node can have a lable `l` and a distance `d` to its parent in the form `l:d`; multiple trees can be separated by a `;`. The format is rather flexible, as is apparent from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format). Both the label and the distance can be omitted, hence `((,),,);` is a valid tree.

- How can one parse a Newick tree to a *Mathematica*-usable object? (The other way around was [already covered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51010/hierarchical-clustering-convert-mathematica-cluster-hierarchy-to-newick-format).)
- How to convert a tree to a `Graph` object?
- How to work with trees? E.g. how to measure distances of leafs/nodes?
- How to display a tree in standard cladogram format (orthogonal edges, correct branching coordinates, vertex and edge labels, etc.)?
- What is the relationship between a phylogenetic tree, a `TreeGraph`, a `Dendrogram`, and a `DendrogramPlot` of the `` "HierarchicalClustering`" `` package?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Download the Phylogenetics` package here**: [Phylogenetics on GitHub](https://github.com/IstvanZachar/Phylogenetics/releases/latest) (direct  link to latest release: [source zip](https://github.com/IstvanZachar/Phylogenetics/archive/1.1.0.zip)), available on PackageData.net [here](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/search/262/Phylogenetics).
Documentation: [notebook](https://github.com/IstvanZachar/Phylogenetics/raw/master/Phylogenetics%20documentation.nb) / [pdf](https://github.com/IstvanZachar/Phylogenetics/raw/master/Phylogenetics%20documentation.pdf) / [dark themed pdf](https://github.com/IstvanZachar/Phylogenetics/raw/master/Phylogenetics%20documentation_dark.pdf) (for the eyestrained).

---

**Version 1.1.0. is out** (2017 01. 31.)

- **added**: `CommonAncestor`, `DivergenceTime`, `AncestorIndex`, `TreeDistanceMatrix`, `TreeTop`, `$PhylogeneticsVersionNumber`.
- **fixed**: Usage message corrections.
- **feature**: Straight `Cladogram` edges, branching according to angle.
- **modified**: `LeafQ` and `NodeQ` now can be applied to a single argument representing a node association.
- **renamed**: `SubnodeIndex` to `DescendantIndex`.
- **modified**: Code was made compatible down to *Mathematica* 10.0. No compatibility before that due to heavy usage of associations.

---

I had to deal with some phylogenetic trees in papers that did not publish exact data for all nodes (e.g. see [this paper](http://www.pnas.org/cgi/doi/10.1073/pnas.1110633108)). I ended up coding a full package to handle Newick and other phylogenetic trees. Hope it could save some time for others.

The `` Phylogenetics` `` package can:

- parse a Newick tree string to a *Mathematica*-usable `Tree` object and write a `Tree` object to a Newick string;
- parse a `Cluster` object of the `` HierarchicalClustering` `` package to a `Tree` and convert a `Tree` to `Cluster` representation;
- test properties of `Tree` objects;
- extract vertices, edges, internal nodes, leafs, sub- and supertrees of `Tree` objects;
- directly calculate various properties of `Tree` objects like paths and distances between vertices;
- convert a `Tree` object to `Graph`, and a tree `Graph` to `Tree`; any tree graph (`TreeGraph`, `ClusteringTree`, etc.) for which `TreeGraphQ` returns `True` can be converted to `Tree`;
- convert a `Tree` object or a tree `Graph` object to `Cladogram` graph,
- provide some example trees in `Newick` and `Cluster` format.

The `Tree` representation follows closely the Newick format, but is a full representation where nothing is omitted. A tree is technically a directed, acyclic graph with an explicit metric defined along the branching dimension (instead of between leaf nodes as with e.g. `Dendrogram`). Each vertex is represented as an association of basic properties minimally required to describe a tree:

- `"Name"` specifies the unique name of the vertex, just like in
  `Graph`; can be any expression.
- `"Label"` specifies the label of the vertex that might appear when the tree is displayed as a graph; can be any expression.
- `"BranchLength"` specifies the numerical distance of the vertex to its parent vertex.
- `"Type"` specifies the type of the vertex, either as `"Node"` for internal nodes or `"Leaf"` for terminal nodes.

Nodes are formatted by default to appear simplified as grey boxes not to increase clutter; the tree structure is best visible in this form.

The package lives on GitHub (link in first line above), and I will try to maintain and develop it as my time allows. **Full documentation and examples** are in the `Phylogenetics documentation.nb` notebook. Please report issues and bugs here. Collaborations are very welcome!

---

### Examples

Load the package and convert a Newick string to a `Tree`.

```
Needs["Phylogenetics`"];

tree = NewickToTree["(A:0.1,B:0.2,((G:.1,H:0.2,I:0.3)C:0.3,D:0.4):0.5)F;"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
TreeToGraph[tree, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are many example trees provided through `PhylogeneticData`. `Cladogram` offers visualization specific for cladistics.

```
tree = NewickToTree[PhylogeneticData["ExampleNewick"]];
Cladogram[tree, EdgeLabels -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 EdgeLabelStyle -> Orange, LayerSizeFunction -> (1 # &), 
 ImageSize -> Medium, VertexSize -> 0.01]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, that unnamed nodes are automatically assigned a unique index to avoid name collision. Vertices, edges, leafs, internal nodes, subtrees and supertrees can be extracted easily:

```
tree = NewickToTree["(A:0.1,B:0.2,((G:.1,H:0.2,I:0.3)C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F;"]
VertexList[tree]
LeafList[tree]
Subtree[tree, "C"]
Supertree[tree, {"H", "D"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Cladogram[tree, GraphHighlight -> Subtree[tree, #], PlotLabel -> #, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"] & /@ {"F", "E", "C", "A"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Graphs can be converted directly to cladograms:

```
graphs = {KaryTree[10, ImageSize -> Tiny], 
  CompleteKaryTree[3, 3, ImageSize -> Tiny], 
  StarGraph[6, ImageSize -> Tiny], 
  TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4}, ImageSize -> Tiny]}
Cladogram[#, Orientation -> Top, ImageSize -> Tiny] & /@ graphs
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hierarchical clusters can be also converted, with similarity values indicating branching distance.

```
cluster = PhylogeneticData["ExampleCluster1"]
tree = ClusterToTree[cluster]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{TreeToGraph[tree, 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", Orientation -> Top}],
 Cladogram[tree, Orientation -> Top, ImageSize -> Small, 
  ImagePadding -> 10],
 DendrogramPlot[cluster, Orientation -> Top, LeafLabels -> (# &)]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Extract paths and measure distances:

```
tree = NewickToTree["(A:0.1,B:0.2,((G:.1,H:0.2,I:0.3)C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F;"];
list = {{"I", "F"}, {"F", "I"}, {"H", "H"},{"H", "B"}};
path = TreePath[tree, #] & /@ list;
dist = TreeDistance[tree, #] & /@ list;

MapThread[
 Cladogram[tree, GraphHighlight -> #1, ImageSize -> Small, 
   PlotLabel -> Row@{#1, ": ", #2}, VertexLabels -> "Name"] &, {path, 
  dist}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A serious phylogenetic tree (from [Parfrey et al. 2011](http://www.pnas.org/cgi/doi/10.1073/pnas.1110633108)):

```
Cladogram[NewickToTree[PhylogeneticData["NewickEukarya"]], 
 ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> {{1, 100}, {1, 1}}, 
 LayerSizeFunction -> (1/5 # &), VertexSize -> None, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[5, Italic], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can also post on http://packagedata.net/

Comment: Posted on packagedata.net, [here](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/search/262/Phylogenetics).

Comment: Today I discovered that if I have a tree graph representing hierarchical clustering, where the `VertexWeight` of each node is the "distance"/"dissimilarity" between subtrees, it can be plotted as a dendrogram using `Dendrogram`.  No need for `DendrogramPlot` from HierarchicalClustering.  The key missing information was the vertex weights of nodes, to represent "dissimilarities".  Up til now I though that it wasn't possible to use `Dendrogram` to do the same we did with `DendrogramPlot`.

Comment: Be aware that this is now partly obsolete as [v12.3](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/05/20/launching-version-12-3-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/) has introduced the new system function `Tree` that similarly to `Phylogenetics`Tree`.