# How to put Mathematica Notebooks and packages on Github?

Tags: programming, development

In the current phase of the project I am working on I am developing a utility package which could easily be open-sourced and shared with the community IF there was an =easy= way to share a notebook / package to GitHub.

I looked at this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30821/how-can-i-commit-files-to-github-by-mathematica) which seems to involve too much work to setup, also it doesn't look 'current' at all.

I also found the [GitLink project](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink) which looks easier to handle.

Before I'll download and install GitLink and perhaps might lose to much valuable time experimenting with it, I would like to know if it is possible to store notebooks to GitHub with GitLink?

What do you suggest, advise on how to store Notebooks and packages to Github?

**=== UPDATE 1-feb-17 ===**

I installed the GitLink paclet from: [this location](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink/releases). It will take time to experiment with this new ( experimental? ) functionality.

Comment: I've just updated my [Phylogenetics package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126497/89) on GitHub, you might find their architecture to your taste. The process is easy: register to GitHub, create a repository, upload your files to it, create a release and share the permanent link pointing to the latest release. You don't have to install anything.

Comment: I see why this might be considered off topic (there is one close vote), but I think it should be left open. It will be a great benefit to the community to clear this up to those who are new to GitHub and version control.

Comment: I am used to working with Java through IntelliJ which makes Github integration really easy. Things like "create a repository, upload your files to it, create a release" which you mention are done automatically in that IDE. But I'll have a look at it. Point is that I can't lose days on this.

Comment: Why do you want to put your package on GitHub? Is it just to publish it, or is to to use version control and develop the package in the open?  GitHub is became the de facto home for open source projects so many people look at it as a package publishing platform. I have seen people upload a zip file of an M package just to publish it. But it's purpose isn't really publishing. It is version control and open collaborative development.  This latter use requires more effort to get familiar with.

Comment: You don't need IDE integration to use GitHub easily (without having to learn to use git from the command line). There are many GUI interfaces. There is GitHub Desktop, which is a much simplified interface. There is SourceTree. Both integrate specifically with GitHub. There are many more git GUIs which can still be conveniently used even if they don't support GitHub specifically. The biggest obstacle is handling notebooks, which aren't easily diffable. Thus it is much more convenient to work with `.m` files containing plain code, rather than notebooks.

Comment: Do you know the GitLink package I asked about in the question? https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink

Comment: Yes, but that is just a way to use git through the Wolfram Language (as opposed to using it through the command line or through a GUI). It does not make things easier unless your goal is automation from within Mathematica.

Comment: I mean, there seem to be plans for adding notebook merge functionality, which would be a great help. But as I understand, it is not *yet* included in GitLink.

Comment: Through the Wolfram Language seems perfect to me.

Comment: You might also be interested in the discussion and links here: [How to share a notebook?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92848/27951)

Comment: @Szabolcs I have installed the GitLink paclet. It comes with tons of Git functions. I will make time in the weekend to experiment with this.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking. If you use git with Java and put your Java code on GitHub already, then you must have a good understanding of what git is good for. Therefore you should be able to handle Mathematica code too. Also, GitLink will not help in any way in handling Mathematica code, it's just a git interface for the Wolfram Language. It is almost as difficult to use as command line git. What is your question then?

Comment: You seriously overestimate my Git skills, Git is not an easy tool. ( I have Git on my system but I use it through the GitHub plugin in IntelliJ ). As I said, I'll have to put more effort into this in the weekend. Thanks so far.

Comment: Your question @szabolcs / answer here turned out to be quite educational to me as well. - http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131101/how-to-distribute-mathematica-packages-as-paclets

Comment: Relevant: [Recommended settings for git when using with Mathematica projects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26174/recommended-settings-for-git-when-using-with-mathematica-projects)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### General comment

Your question suggests that you might be on the wrong or at least on a stony path. Let me try to clear some things up even if it is not strictly Mathematica correlated.

Yes, you can share your package via GitHub, but you might confuse things here. The primary purpose of GitHub is to provide an online platform for the *version control system* git. When you publish a complete Mathematica package, it is more like publishing a release of software. GitHub has this feature and lets you publish releases, but it is not its primary purpose.

You should use git when you want to track the progress during the coding of the package. If you want to make your code public or you are working with several other people on the same code (the other main purpose of git), then GitHub is the place to go. With git you can track changes, you can work on several features simultaneously, you can track bugs by comparing different versions of files, and much much more. RM wrote an excellent answer once that explained package development in more detail:

- [Recommended settings for git when using with Mathematica projects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26180/187)

Additional helpful features of GitHub are that

- you have an issue tracker where people can tell you about things that don't work
- you can create documentation pages quickly because it provides a markdown wiki for each repository
- you can upload several releases of your software that users can download

### When you don't know git, don't start with GitLink

GitLink is an API that makes it possible to use git from within Mathematica. If you don't know git, then this might not be the way you want to go. It is like using MathLink without knowing C.

If you indeed want to learn how to use version control, then start with a [simple tutorial](https://de.atlassian.com/git/tutorials) to understand the basics. I don't expect you to work on commandline but there are very nice GUIs for git. On OSX or Windows I highly recommend [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), and on Linux, you could use for instance `gitk`.

I want to note that [IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) as other good IDEs as well has extremely nice git support right out of the box. If you use it with the [Mathematica Plugin](http://wlplugin.halirutan.de/) you can develop packages and have all those features in one tool.

### If you only want to share the final package

Well, you can go to GitHub as well. Just create an account and a new repository. Put in a decent `README.md` and upload your `package.zip` in the *release* section. You don't have to know any git command for this. It can all be done with some mouse clicks.

### How should I see "paclets" in this context?

Paclets are the future way how you *should* distribute your packages. The problem is that the documentation is currently non-existent. My background info on paclets is very vague, but I believe paclets started as containers for additional data like CUDA drivers or for all the `XXXData` functions like `ChemicalData`. I'm not sure if it was planned from the beginning, but paclets seem to be the future of package-distribution.

For a good resource on how to use them with your own packages, you should read Szabolcs post:

- [How to distribute Mathematica packages as paclets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131101/how-to-distribute-mathematica-packages-as-paclets)

Comment: This is merely the outline of an answer. If there are things I should explain in greater depth, you are welcome to leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks. This cleared up a lot of points. - How should I see "paclets" in this context? When should you use paclets?

Comment: @niloderoock See my update at the end of my post.

Comment: Interesting. This is clearly a volatile area.

Answer (score 13):

There is [`ResourceFunction["SaveReadableNotebook"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SaveReadableNotebook):

> `SaveReadableNotebook` can be used to create notebook files that are well suited for version control systems that look at changes to files on a line-by-line basis.

It is better to use it with the option `"ExcludedCellOptions"`:

```
ResourceFunction["SaveReadableNotebook"]["original.nb", "original_readable.nb", 
  "ExcludedCellOptions" -> {CellChangeTimes, ExpressionUUID, CellLabel}];
```

The formatted notebook file still opens normally:

```
NotebookOpen["original_readable.nb"]
```