# Mathematica history: restoring previous version

Tags: save, history

I have read such page: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/FindTheEditHistoryOfANotebook.html

So we can see when each line has been modified. But can we restore to the associated version ? If not I don't really see the point of this functionnality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But can we restore to the associated version?

No. Only the modification times are stored.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you want can be implemented with Git/GitHub.

See this question: [How to put Mathematica Notebooks and packages on Github?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136634/how-to-put-mathematica-notebooks-and-packages-on-github)