# Location to post Mathematica resources

Tags: education, publishing

I compiled a set of notes that I will keep updating.

Is there a dedicated site where tutorials/explanatory notes can be shared to help other users?

Comment: Have you already seen the [Notebook Archive](https://notebookarchive.org/)?

Comment: Thanks, I will post it there!

Comment: "that I will keep updating" - that might not make the Notebook Archive the best choice if you want to keep updating your resources. As I understand it, once a file is submitted, you may not be able to modify it again. But I have never actually submitted anything to the Archive. An alternative might be GitHub, but notebooks do not really lend themselves to that format; packages are better, as discussed before e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136634/27951) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26174/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB There is [`ResourceFunction["SaveReadableNotebook"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SaveReadableNotebook) which "saves a notebook to a file that is formatted to maximize readability when viewing changes in version control systems."

Comment: In what format do you keep your notes in?

Comment: I keep it as a Mathematica Notebook. @Kuba

Comment: @MarcoB I already uploaded it to Notebook Archive. I will try to find out whether I can update once I get feedback.