# How to add wolfram mathematica notebook on github?

Tags: notebooks

I am setting up a GitHub repository with the notebooks I created during my master's project. Among them, some are from Mathematica. Is there a better way to upload the files? Because the way I uploaded them, the code becomes quite confusing.

How it appears on GitHub:
[image]

How the notebook looks:
[image]

Comment: I thought the practice was to convert it to .m file (package file) and save that instead.  Saving the raw notebook (even though it is plain text) might not be useful for diff's and looking at it. I remember now there was discussion on this before. May be in this forum or at community,

Comment: see for example [how-to-put-mathematica-notebooks-and-packages-on-github](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136634/how-to-put-mathematica-notebooks-and-packages-on-github)

Comment: If you use github only for storing codes, I think you can merely ignore this issue. The codes you see on github are just the low level stuffs behind the notebook, see e.g. `tutorial/ManipulatingNotebooks#31306`.