# How to automatically label the cluster distances in a DendrogramPlot?

Tags: plotting, formatting, labeling, style, cluster-analysis

I have a distance matrix `data`, and want to visualize it as below:

[image]

The current codes I am using is:

```
data={{0., 1.2, 1.73, 3.57, 3.22, 3.17}, {1.2, 0., 0.53, 2.37, 2.05, 
  1.97}, {1.73, 0.53, 0., 1.85, 1.54, 1.45}, {3.57, 2.37, 1.85, 0., 
  0.42, 0.41}, {3.22, 2.05, 1.54, 0.42, 0., 0.31}, {3.17, 1.97, 1.45, 
  0.41, 0.31, 0.}};

DendrogramPlot[DirectAgglomerate[data,Style[#, 16] & /@ {"G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G6"},Linkage -> "Single"], LeafLabels -> Automatic,Orientation -> Right,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, Axes -> {True, False},AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, ImageSize -> 560, AxesStyle -> {{Directive[Gray, 12], Arrowheads[.02]}, Automatic},AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

which results:

[image]

The cluster distances information can be easily obtained by:

`DirectAgglomerate[data,Style[#,16]&/@{"G1","G2","G3","G4","G5","G6"},Linkage->"Single"]`

which is:

> Cluster[Cluster[G1,Cluster[G2,G3,**0.53**,1,1],**1.2**,1,2],Cluster[Cluster[G5,G6,**0.31**,1,1],G4,**0.41**,2,1],**1.45**,3,3]

how can I label the cluster distances into the `DendrogramPlot` automatically?

PS: I noticed there is already a similar post [here:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/visualize-cluster-distances-in-dendrogramplot?rq=1) , but the answer does not label the distances as text something like the [Python implementation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917779/how-to-plot-and-annotate-hierarchical-clustering-dendrograms-in-scipy-matplotlib).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post-processing the `DendrogramPlot` output to extract the cluster distances and placing them in appropriate locations:

```
dplt = DendrogramPlot[DirectAgglomerate[data, 
    Style[#, 16] & /@ {"G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G6"}, 
    Linkage -> "Single"], LeafLabels -> Automatic, 
   Orientation -> Right, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   Axes -> {True, False}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, ImageSize -> 560, 
   AxesStyle -> {{Directive[Gray, 12], Arrowheads[.02]}, Automatic}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/2];
```

( thanks: BobHanlon for the simpler version for `rule`)

```
rule = Line[a : {_, {x_, y1_}, {x_, y2_}, _}] :> {Line[a], Black, 
         FontSize -> 16, Text[x, {x, (y1 + y2)/2}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}]};

dplt /. rule
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively:

```
labels = Cases[dplt, Line[a : {_, {x_, y1_}, {x_, y2_},_}] :>
   {Black, FontSize -> 16, Text[x, {x, (y1 + y2)/2}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}]}, Infinity];

Show[dplt, Graphics@labels]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ... this works when `Orientation->Right`. For other orientations, similar rules can be constructed.

Comment: I should learn more on the programmar details of Mathematica. Thank you!

Comment: @LCFactorization, glad it worked for you. Pity there is no option that gives control on the labeling directly. Thank you for the Accept.

Comment: An alternative rule: `line : Line[{_, {x_, y1_}, {x_, y2_}, _}] :> Sequence[line, {Black, Text[Style[NumberForm[x, {3, 2}], 12], {x, (y1 + y2)/2}, {1.25, 0}]}]` This also would have to be modified or generalized to handle a different  [Orientation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/HierarchicalClustering/ref/Orientation.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon, thank you, that's much cleaner.